# Last modified date of a file in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, file

I'm creating a function that displays when the last file was modified. I was trying to make this code works, but it doesn't display anything.

```
function send() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "file.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    myfunction(xhttp);
 }
 
function myfunction(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var date = xmlDoc.lastModified;
    alert(date);
}
```

Comment: `file.xml` right now is just a string, it's not a file. `lastModified` isn't a defined function for a string

Comment: it means that i need to open my file or what?

Comment: What is file.xml actually supposed to be other than a string? is it on the server? Is it on the client?

Comment: thats on the server

Answer (score 0):

the `lastModified` method operates on a DOM element. In your example, the file is a String.